# Parse cloud code object.save() not working

Tags: parsing, parse-cloud-code

I’m new to Parse and Cloud Code. I’m trying to initialize a new user’s data via a cloud code function. The function queries my “initial items objects” (a total of 223 items), then loops through each one creating a new “item” for the user. Inside the loop the new item’s fields are set and ends by calling save(). The function seems to be working, however, instead of saving 223 new items, only 9 are created. I placed a log statement after the save to see if in fact that loop was iterating through the 223 items … and it is. Below is my cloud code and log.

Any thoughts as to why only 9 items are being saved? The 9 items that are saved look fine.

---

```
Parse.Cloud.define("initializeNewUser", function(request, response) {
    var InitialItemsObject = Parse.Object.extend("InitialParseItems");
    var itemsQuery = new Parse.Query(InitialItemsObject);
    itemsQuery.limit(500);
    itemsQuery.find().then(function(results) {
    console.log('Found ' + results.length +' Items.');
    var user = request.user;
    var ACL = new Parse.ACL(user);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var defaultItem = results[i];

        var item = new Parse.Object("Items");  
        item.set('itemID', defaultItem.get('itemID'));          
        item.set('author', user);           
        item.set('groupID', defaultItem.get('groupID'));            
        item.set('itemName', defaultItem.get('itemName'));
        item.set('itemNote', defaultItem.get('itemNote'));
        item.set('itemChecked', defaultItem.get('itemChecked'));
        item.set('itemIsFavorite', defaultItem.get('itemIsFavorite'));
        item.set('itemSelected', defaultItem.get('itemSelected'));
        item.set('itemStruckOut', defaultItem.get('itemStruckOut'));
        item.set('manualSortOrder', defaultItem.get('manualSortOrder'));
        item.set('productID', defaultItem.get('productID'));
        item.set('itemTimestamp', defaultItem.get('itemTimestamp'));
        item.setACL(ACL);
        item.save();
        //console.log(defaultItem.get('itemName') + ' saved.');
    }

    // success has been moved inside the callback for query.find()
    console.log('Successfully initialize ' + results.length + ' Items.');
    response.success(results.length);
},

function(error) {
    // Make sure to catch any errors, otherwise you may see a "success/error not called" error in Cloud Code.
    console.log('Failed to initialize Items. Error code: ' + error.code + ' ' + error.message);
    response.error("Failed to initialize Items. Error code: " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
});
});
```

---

I2015-07-17T15:16:38.661Z]v22 Ran cloud function initializeNewUser for user va0TTGwOk7 with:
  Input: {}
  Result: 223
I2015-07-17T15:16:38.930Z]Found 223 Items.
I2015-07-17T15:16:39.141Z]Successfully initialize 223 Items.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a few comments.

1.) on line 7 you set user with request.user. I'm not sure how you are sending your data, but I've always used request.params.[insert item name]

2.) The next big thing is that by using "then()" you are using promises. at the end of every "then", you should be returning a promise. That means you wouldn't say "item.save()" but "return item.save()". Saving is a promise also so you will need to return those. Here should be your general promise pattern.

```
SomePromise.then( function(a)
            {return promiseA} ).then( function(b)
                                {return PromiseB} ).then( function(c)
                                                    {response.success}, function(error){response.error})
```

3.) When you are saving lots of items, you either have to use "saveAll()" or make an array of promises, then save them all at once. A good rule of thumb is to use a promise array every time you are saving lots of things in an array. Here is the portion of the Cloud Code developer guide that will show you the correct format https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises-promises-in-parallel